# How to find free time slots from appointment table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to list the free time slots using an AvailableTimeTable and an AppointmentTable. I already have the AppointmentTable in my project, but I’m thinking of adding the AvailableTimeTable to be able to list the free time slots for a specific user.

AvailableTimeTable (TAVT)

```
Id
Day (0 to 6)
Start time
End time
```

AppointmentTable (TAP)

```
Id 
Start datetime
End datetime
```

Data example for AvailableTimeTable – Monday March 7 , 2016 - This is the blocks of time user1 is available on Mondays

```
Id            day        start      end
1             1             08:00     10:00
2             1             10:15     12:00                         (15 min break here)
3             1             13:00     14:00  
4             1             14:15     16:00                         (15 min break here)
```

Data example for AppointmentTable - This is user1's schedule for Monday March 7 , 2016

```
Id            Start datetime               End datetime
1             2016-03-07-09:00             2016-03-07-10:00         (9-10 am)
2             2016-03-07-10:15             2016-03-07-11:00         (10:15-11am)
```

According to the data above, the free time slots for that day (for user1) are:

```
08:00 – 09:00
11:00 – 12:00
13:00 – 14:00
14:15 – 16:00
```

**Time intervals would always be in multiple of 15 minutes**

Not sure how the query should look like. I'm not even sure my AvailableTimeTable concept is good. Maybe it should represent the opposite, store block of time where the user IS NOT available. Maybe the query would be simpler?

Comment: Is the time interval always in multiple of `15`? And if user is on break from `14` to `14:15` then would that account for free time slot? Shouldn't free time slot be `13` - `14` and `14:15` to `16`?

Comment: Youre right, I fixed the free time slots from the example. Yes, the time intervals would always be in multiple of 15 minutes.

Comment: Oups, forgot to answer your question:  _if user is on break from 14 to 14:15 then would that account for free time slot?_ The answer is no, that time block doesn't account for free time.

Answer (score -1):

You can start from here:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN time(ap.start) = av.start or time(ap.end) < av.end THEN time(ap.end)
         WHEN time(ap.start) > av.start or time(ap.end) = av.end THEN av.start
         ELSE av.start
       END available_start_time
     , CASE
         WHEN time(ap.start) = av.start or time(ap.end) < av.end THEN av.end
         WHEN time(ap.start) > av.start or time(ap.end) = av.end THEN time(ap.start)
         ELSE av.end
       END available_end_time
  FROM AvailableTimeTable av
    LEFT JOIN AppointmentTable ap
      ON date(ap.start) = :p_date
        AND weekday(ap.start)+1 = av.day
        AND time(ap.start) between av.start and av.end
        AND time(ap.end) between av.start and av.end
```

This will cover only basic and constrained cases (ej. max 2 appointments per available time row).
Can you have a 15 min appointment? 
Can you have adjacent appointments?
I think it is better storing available time in chunks of 15 minutes.
Otherwise you should run a cursor to merge adjacent appointments and then after look for the available blocks of time.

Comment: Event b overlaps event a if event b starts before event a ends and ends after event a starts.

Comment: Thanks, will start playing with that